# Elasticsearch, allow same network access only, using domain names?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to allow access to elasticsearch at `example.com:9200` from machines at `example.com`

Can we specify DNS for host, and let client access it via DNS?

```
 ES setting: network.host = example.com and 
 client access it via example.com:9200 ?
```

Or at least can we do?

```
network.host = [_site_ , _local_, public-ip-of-example-com]
client access it via example.com:9200 ?
```

Comment: can your client ping example.com?

Comment: @basitraza yes it can

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your server setup, a way around bind elasticsearch server on local interface server it via reverse-proxy like nginx, haproxy.

so your client can access it using example.com if the reverse proxy is listening on port 80.

Comment: or try network.host = 0.0.0.0, may be firewall restricting outside access?